# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object When using Featurewiz

Tags: python, feature-selection

I'm using Featurewiz for feature selection.
Before using it, I aplly TF-IDF on X_train, and peek the best n features that got the highest score in TF-IDF.
Those features is what I send to X_train_Selected to featurewiz.

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=n)
    X_train_tf = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train['Content'])
    X_test_tf = tfidf.transform(X_test['Content'])

    # Update the TF-IDF vectorizer with the selected features
    selected_feature_indices = np.argsort(tfidf.idf_)[-n:]
    tfidf.vocabulary_ = {feature: index for index, feature in enumerate(selected_feature_indices)}
    X_train_final = X_train_tf[:, selected_feature_indices].toarray()
    X_test_final = X_test_tf[:, selected_feature_indices].toarray()
```

After that I convert to DataFrame so featurewiz could get it.

BUT
I keep getting the follwoing error:

```
    X_train_selected = features.fit_transform(X_train_final, y_train)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py:140 in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:881 in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featurewiz\featurewiz.py:2943 in fit
    features, X_sel = featurewiz(df, target, self.corr_limit, self.verbose, self.sep,

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featurewiz\featurewiz.py:562 in featurewiz
    dataname = uniq.fit_transform(dataname)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py:140 in wrapped
    data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featurewiz\my_encoders.py:2007 in fit_transform
    self.fit(X)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featurewiz\my_encoders.py:1978 in fit
    self.new_column_names, self.transformed_flag = EDA_make_column_names_unique(X)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featurewiz\my_encoders.py:2023 in EDA_make_column_names_unique
    newls = ser.map(remove_special_chars).values.tolist()

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:4539 in map
    new_values = self._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py:890 in _map_values
    new_values = map_f(values, mapper)

  File pandas\_libs\lib.pyx:2924 in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\featurewiz\my_encoders.py:2022 in <lambda>
    remove_special_chars =  lambda x:re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9_]+', '', x)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\re.py:210 in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I've tried to change X_train_final to be str but it didn't help, Iv'e tried to remove duplicates from columns and more. Ofcorse i've cleaned the data.

Will appreceate you help!!

Iv'e tried everything, but there is no much documentation about Featurewiz

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.